# Keeping google gsuite legacy with custom domain but changing only email MX

Tags: google-gsuite

**TL;DR**

Can I keep using my legacy gsuite account (thinking about my android phone, mostly), while only changing the MX of my custom domain to another provider?

**Context**

I have a legacy gsuite account, which will become paying in the next months.

Google will apparently provide a solution to move everything to a normal gmail account, which will be fine and enough for my playstore purchases/android phone, but not for my emails which are bound to a custom domain (and was the reason why I started with gsuite, all these years ago).

I want to move my emails, and only my emails for now, to a new (paying) provider, sooner than later, to have time to experiment and test before the plug is completely pulled from the legacy gsuite.

If I just change the MX of my domain, will the rest of the current gsuite (including Android) carry on working as normal?

I would think so, but I could not find any conclusive answer, and I'd rather not being without a working phone or working email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I have done it: yes, it is possible to update all the relevant email DNS settings (dmarc, dkim, spf, MX) and still use the Google suite.